# VB Ubuntu says disk full but not

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, virtualbox, gparted, disk-usage

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 via VirtualBox from win11. Recently I had to extend the space allocated for the machine. I did that using `gparted` util. It was fine for a while but now I am getting warnings about disk space being full.

There is no way my data are 100GB. Disk manager shows disk full but when it counts data, its only 30GB (although in the preview it is full - see screenshots).

[image]

[image]

I tried `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5` but it says: there is nothing to do.

Here is gparted screen:

[image]

Here are outputs of several tools:

`df -h`:

```
FileSystem           Size  Used  Free Use% Mounted to
tmpfs                676M  1,5M  675M   1% /run
/dev/sda5             97G   92G  329M 100% /
tmpfs                3,4G     0  3,4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                3,4G     0  3,4G   0% /run/qemu
/dev/sda1            511M  4,0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
Shared               953G  416G  538G  44% /media/sf_Shared
tmpfs                676M  108K  676M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0              59M   59M     0 100% /media/user/VBox_GAs_6.1.342
```

`parted /dev/sda print free`:

```
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 106GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Volume table: msdos

Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End   Size  Type       FileSystem   switch
       1024B    1049kB  1048kB              Free space
 1     1049kB   538MB   537MB     primary   fat32           boot
       538MB    539MB   1048kB              Free space
 2     539MB    106GB   106GB     extended
 5     539MB    106GB   106GB     logical   ext4
       106GB    106GB   1049kB              Free space
```

`lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0  63,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2105
loop2    7:2    0  63,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2182
loop3    7:3    0  74,1M  1 loop /snap/core22/1033
loop4    7:4    0  73,9M  1 loop /snap/core22/864
loop5    7:5    0 262,5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/3779
loop6    7:6    0 266,6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/3836
loop7    7:7    0 349,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop8    7:8    0   497M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
loop9    7:9    0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop11   7:11   0  40,4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
loop12   7:12   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
loop13   7:13   0  39,1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21184
sda      8:0    0  99,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  98,6G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                 /
sr0     11:0    1  58,7M  0 rom  /media/user/VBox_GAs_6.1.342
```

Do you have any idea why the free space is not available (marked as used)?

Comment: You did not count all files on your filesystem, but only ones that your user had access to. Try running baobab with sudo: `sudo baobab` or `sudo du -hxd 1 /` to count all files

Comment: You are right! There were 60GB of temporary Docker files in /var/ folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk manager doesn't count all files on the filesystem, but only the ones that are available to me as a user. Running `sudo du -hxd 1 /` showed where were hidden files. Thanks to Mateusz for comment.